# Logging the type of a variable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to find the variable type of `context` in Android Studio by logging it console. However, I get two different results when I

1. First, stored it in a variable `typeContext` and then logged it
2. Directly logged `context!!::class.simpleName`

The o/p were

1. `MainActivity`
2. `com.example.android.testapp.MainActivity@95580a4!!::class.simpleName`

unexpectedly different for both cases. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    val typeContext = context!!::class.simpleName

    Log.d("my_debug", "type of context is given by: $typeContext or $context!!::class.simpleName")

    {....}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case, Kotlin is not parsing your string interpolation the way you expect. It thinks that the `$` in `$context!!::class.simpleName` means you want to interpolate the value of `$context` (followed by the string literal `!!...`).

To fix it, use `${...}` to specify exactly what expression you want to interpolate.

In other words, change `$context!!::class.simpleName` to `${context!!::class.simpleName}`.